# Access-Control-Allow-Origin em diferentes ambientes

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

Estou com um problema bem estranho: o mesmo código funciona local e em prod, mas não funciona em homolog.

Basicamente, o problema é homolog (logo no login) é esse:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Estávamos com esse problema em prod e conseguimos resolver, porém, ao publicar em homolog, encontramos esse problema novamente.

No Startup da publicação, permitimos todas as origens:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Isso resolveu nosso problema local e em prod, mas continua com problemas em homolog.

Nosso front é em angular e não mexemos em nada em como foram feitas as requisições.

Comment: Isso deveria resolver o problema, porém, dê um check nas configurações do web.config do seu ambiente de homologação. Qual a versão do IIS?

Comment: De acordo com o painel do AWS: 64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 v1.2.0 running IIS 8.5. E as configs em homolog funcionavam algumas semanas atrás. Sem nenhuma alteração, parou de funcionar. Fizemos um teste agora pegando o mesmo código que está em prod e publicamos em homolog, alterando apenas o web.config e não resolveu. Pode ser algum problema de acesso do servidor do front com o servidor de api?